# Get date from week day(monday-sunday) and its week date (any date between that week)

Tags: postgresql

For example, Day of Week set to Friday and the week date set to August 13, 2019, then the first week should be the week ending Friday, August 15, 2019.

In the above example, if week date set to August 17, 2019, then the first week would show is the week ending Friday, August 22, 2019.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show some code you have written?

Comment: You may want to use the [`date_trunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) function.